# Problem with understanding change of coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

I am studying the article "On the Lyapunov instability in Newtonian dynamics" by Burgos, Maderna and Patternain (https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.11962).

I am having some trouble understanding the choice of coordinates. Given the Cauchy problem:

$\ddot{x}_{\epsilon} = -\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\nabla U (x_{\epsilon})$

$x_{\epsilon} = p$

$\dot{x}_{\epsilon}(0) = v$,

where $\epsilon>0$, and $U(x)=g(f(x))$, with f a $C^2$ class function and g a $C^3$ class function that vanishes only at zero.

The authors said that in order to isolate the limit in the above problem they will consider the flow $\phi$ given by

$\partial_t \phi = \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|^2}, \phi(0, x)=x$

I didn't undertand this choice of flow to change the coordinates, why gradient of f divided by the square of the module of gradient of f?

I thought that maybe it is somewhat related to differential geometry, but I am not sure.

Thanks for any help.